# Loader for "Profile" contact's details

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am basing my code on the Login sample supplied with Android Studio. That sample contains code to populate an `AutoCompleteTextView` with email addresses related to the device's `ContactsContract.Profile` contact. i.e. the phone's owner, me.

I need to keep using the `LoaderCallbacks` interface methods - `onCreateLoader()` and `onLoaderFinished()`.

I want to fetch **extra details on the contact** like:

- phone number
- given name
- family name

---

To achieve this, I have tried adding extra fields to the `ProfileQuery` interface defined in the sample (that works correctly to fetch email address):

```
private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            // these fields as per Android Studio sample
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,

            // these fields added by me
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME
    };
}
```

---

I have modified the `onCreateLoader()` method to remove the sample's WHERE clause in the hope to get the extra data:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            // select all fields
            null, null,

            // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
            // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
}
```

---

For what it is worth, at the moment my `onLoadFinished()` just logs the received data out:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Log.d("xxx", cursor.getString(0) + cursor.getString(1) + cursor.getString(2) + cursor.getString(3) + cursor.getString(4));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

---

I would like each cursor row to give me a complete set of data relating to the Profile contact. Instead, I am getting seemingly random fields from that contact.

My `CursorLoader` construction is clearly wrong, but I do not know how to fix that.

How can I get the following details from my Profile contact:

- email address
- phone number
- given name
- family name?

Comment: related: [Best way to access all the details of android contacts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506985/best-way-to-access-all-the-details-of-android-contacts)

Answer (score 0):

The code above is based on a misunderstanding of how the contacts data is stored.

The `Uri` being used is pointing to the `ContactsContract.Data` table. The [Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) explain the structure of this table. Each row in the table is an item of information, not a contact. e.g. an email address, a phone number etc.

---

The projection defined is specific to email addresses (since the sample deals only with emails). A more general projection that can handle different data types could be something like:

```
private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA2,
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA3,
    };
}
```

As the docs explain:

> DATA1 is an indexed column and should be used for the data element
>   that is expected to be most frequently used in query selections. For
>   example, in the case of a row representing email addresses DATA1
>   should probably be used for the email address itself, while DATA2 etc
>   can be used for auxiliary information like type of email address.

.

> For example,
>   Phone.NUMBER is the same as Data.DATA1.

---

The query then returns a cursor row for each piece of information in the Profile contact. In my case, the 3 email addresses I stored, a phone number and my name.

For each row the `Data.MIMETYPE` column defines how the other data columns should be read. The mimetypes can be queried based on constants declared in `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` class, such as:

- `Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`
- `Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`
- `StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`
- `Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`